# How to update or insert row with many-to-many relation in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, insert, many-to-many

I have 3 tables office, service and relation between them in office_service table. Here is an example of tables:

```
Offices
+----+---------+
| id | street  |
+----+---------+

Services
+----+---------+
| id |service  |
+----+---------+

Office_Service
+----+-----------+------------+
| id | id_office | id_service |
+----+-----------+------------+
```

I have offices which no have services, and offices which change one or several services.

On the office page I show information about it and `<select multiple>` tag with all services. If my query "SELECT id_service FROM office_service WHERE id_office = $office_id", return something I mark "selected" appropriate `<option>`

And I don't get how to do if the office change a service, or the office which no have a service will get it. How to implement this with MySQL, or I need check the office_service table before update/insert action of the office?

Update: When a user click save button how to find out what to do - insert, delete or do nothing with rows in the Office_Service table?

Comment: if an office adds a service, you insert a new `id_office, id_service` tuple. If they remove a service, you delete the matching tuple. that's all.

Comment: How to implement this behavior? MySQL queries  or I need select rows and then check in code if selected rows equal POST data or how?

Comment: for these sorts of situations, I find it's easier to just delete all the m-t-m table records in a transaction, then insert whatever's been submitted from the client.  much easier than separately figuring out the difference(s) between the submitted form and what's in the db, then building appropriate insert/delete statements.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't think about this.

Answer (score 0):

If the intent is to show a list of all services, and which of those services is available at a given office. Assuming the (id_service, id_office) tuple is UNIQUE in `office_service` then something like this:

```
SELECT s.id
     , s.service
     , os.id_service IS NOT NULL AS `service_exists_for_this_office`
  FROM services s
  LEFT 
  JOIN office_service os
    ON os.id_service = s.id
 WHERE os.id_office = '42'
```

The third expression in the select list will return a `1` if there is a matching row in `office_service`, and will return a `0` if the row doesn't exist.

To add a service to an office,

```
INSERT INTO office_service (id_office, id_service) VALUES (42, 7);
```

To remove that service from an office:

```
DELETE FROM office_service WHERE id_office = 42 and id_service = 7;
```